# Unable to reverse integers in an array, fails halfway thru

Tags: java, arrays, int, reverse

I want to reverse the integers in Array 's'. I can't figure out why the output is reversing on itself. Link for code
http://ideone.com/REuGYt

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int[] s = {4,5,6,7,8};
        for (int x = 0; x < s.length; x++) {
            s[x] = s[(s.length - x) -1];
            System.out.println(s[x]);
        }
    }
}

//outputs 
8
7
6
7
8
```

Comment: you are mirroring, swap elements instead of overriding

Comment: Either create a new array or use a swap method...

Answer (score 1):

You are only copying the right side values to the left side values; you aren't switching the values from both sides.  Instead of just copying the right side to the left side, swap their values.  Replace

```
s[x] = s[(s.length - x) -1];
```

with

```
int temp = s[x];
s[x] = s[(s.length - x) -1];
s[(s.length - x) -1] = temp;
```

Additionally, you will need to stop your `for` loop halfway through the array, before `x` reaches `s.length/2`, or else the second half will swap the values back to their original locations.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    List<Integer> reversed = Arrays.asList(4,5,6,7,8);
    Collections.reverse(reversed);
```

It'll build a collection, then reverse it.

Answer (score 1):

You're changing the values in the array as you iterate.  When you get halfway through your array you begin to print out values that you previously wrote in.  This makes it appear mirrored.  One fix is by using two arrays:

```
int[] s = {4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
int[] rev = new int[s.length];

for (int x = 0; x < s.length; x++) {
    rev[x] = s[(s.length - x) - 1];
    System.out.println(rev[x]);
}
```